# Mysql instance in google cloud console (Appengine) crashed

Tags: mysql, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql

I have a sql database on google cloud console it stopped working suddenly. I am not able to start, stop or restart my instance. I could not restore backup from the instance. My crash log says

```
insertId: "s=xxxxxx"  
 logName: "projects/xxxxxxxx/logs/cloudsql.googleapis.com%2Fmysql.err"  
 receiveTimestamp: "2019-11-19T09:45:40.414048508Z"  
 resource: {
  labels: {
   database_id: "xxxxxxxxxx"    
   project_id: "xxxxx"    
   region: "xxxxxx"    
  }
  type: "cloudsql_database"   
 }
 severity: "ERROR"  
 textPayload: "InnoDB: Progress in percent: 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 2019-11-19T09:45:39.080501Z 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Trying to access page number 11 in space 5412, space name billing/with_state_1, which is outside the tablespace bounds. Byte offset 0, len 16384, i/o type read. If you get this error at mysqld startup, please check that your my.cnf matches the ibdata files that you have in the MySQL server."  
 timestamp: "2019-11-19T09:45:39.080618Z"
```

How could I get the mysql dump file or how to restart the instance. Please give me solution. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to have proper help with this kind of issue please [open an issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=491274&template=1161130) with the Google Cloud Platform team with the title "Cloud SQL instance hangs and won't restart". After creating the issue in the platform a Google Engineer will help you.

Add in the body of the issue your project Id and the name of the Cloud SQL instance.

Comment: I opened an issue using the link you provided. hope this helps us. @Chris32

Comment: they helped us so much.